# in tabbar application with navigation controller how to start from first view in hierarchy of tabbar

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have tabbar based application, I want to start each time tab is pressed to start with first view they are associated with. Problem is it starts with first view when its a start of application but while using application i may navigate deep in to one tab and now what to do if i want to start it again with main view associated with that tab which is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tabbar delegates to override this behaviour. The `UITabBarControllerDelegate` is documented here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

You would want to look at:
`tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`

Everytime this delegate method is triggered you can trigger the corresponding navigation controller's `popToRootViewController:animated` method. Normally you'd have your app delegate be the tabbar controller delegate also, but that's up to your implementation.